# Window.chrome object is undefined in Electron App

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to measuring First Paint Time with Electron  (formerly Atom-Shell). A close approximation is available in Chrome called `window.chrome.loadTimes()`, which returns an object.

But with Electron `window.chrome` object is undefined.

I do this

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() { 
    var preloadJS = __dirname + '/TestPreloadJS.js'
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, show: true, preload: preloadJS}); 
    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://crawlbin.com/');
    mainWindow.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    }); 

    mainWindow.webContents.on('dom-ready', function() {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log(process.versions['electron'])");
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('Chrome version: ' + getChromeVersion())");
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('window.chrome:' + window.chrome)");
    });     
});
```

That display this in Console

> [4792:0115/150607:INFO:renderer_main.cc(200)] Renderer process started
>   [456:0115/150608:INFO:renderer_main.cc(200)] Renderer process started
>   [4776:0115/150608:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "0.31.0", source: (1)
>   [4776:0115/150608:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Chrome version: 44", source: (1)
>   [4776:0115/150608:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "window.chrome:undefined", source:
>   (1)

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. I read somewhere that `window.chrome` would not be available, but I can't remember the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2042#issuecomment-114667969
For time being it is not supported!!